# Matlab: Database. Rewrite SQL

Tags: sql, database, matlab

This is my code for SELECT-query. `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (DateField = Date)`

```
 function out = SQL_Simple( DBName, TableName, Date, DateField, SortField, Limits )

 logintimeout(60);
 conurl = ['jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=' DBName];
 conn = database('','','','sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver', conurl);


 Limits = Limits + 1;
 sql = ['SELECT * FROM ' TableName ];
 sql = [sql ' WHERE (' DateField ' = ' Date ')'];

 interest = fetch(exec(conn, sql));


 %sql = [sql ' ORDER BY ' SortField ' DESC' ];
 %sql = [sql ' LIMIT ' Limits];

 close(conn);
 out = interest.Data;
 end
```

and it doesn't work.

What's wrong with this query?

`DateField` have type `adDate`.
`Date` have format `dd.mm.yyyy`.

p.s:

This is the table in db:

```
DBTable.Name = "MyTable"
DBTable.Columns.Append "StrField", adVarWChar, 160
DBTable.Columns.Append "DoubleField", adDouble, 40
DBTable.Columns.Append "IntField", adInteger
DBTable.Columns.Append "CurField", adCurrency
DBTable.Columns.Append "Today", adDate
```

`DateField='Today'`. (in `matlab` code)

I trying to write something like this:

```
 sql = ['SELECT * FROM ' TableName ];
 sql = [sql ' WHERE (' DateField ' = ''' Date ''');' ];
```

it doesn't work too :( (here `Date = '2010-12-31 00:00:00.0'`, DateField = `'Today'`)

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*?

Comment: because it return 0, but not the big amount of rows

Comment: additional question: it use mysql dialect of sql, not mssql?

Comment: It doesn't make sense for DateField to have type adDate, surely DateField should be a string containing the column name in your DB table? Can you post the table schema, i.e. what columns your table (in TableName) has?

Comment: @Dan ok, add information about db into question

Comment: And have you tried this query in a dbms? Where did you create your database?

Comment: @Dan 
in `VBA`, using `ADOX`.
yeah, i trying this query, but it returns `0` :\ without `WHERE`-condition it works fine.
i can't understand, how to change date in matlab, which mssql can use.

Comment: So you have tried the query in VBA and it is giving you the same non result as Matlab? Then I guess the problem is not with your Matlab code but with your database?

Comment: Are you certain there are data entries for that date? How are you verifying this?

Comment: yes, i'm verifying this code, yes. But in VBA i write this code: `Request = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (Today=#" + Format(D, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") + "#)"` <- it works.

Comment: okay, i understand this query. (work with dates under mssql ) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you post the actual error mesasge.  In this case, though, I think one problem is the date comparison.  You need quotes around "date".  Try:

```
sql = [sql ' WHERE (' DateField ' = ''' Date ''')'];
```

for the second SQL line.

Comment: not, it doesn't work, cause `Date` have format `dd.mm.yyyy` and `DateField` is `adDate`. So, how to change `Date` to format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms` ?

Comment: use the matlab functions `datenum` and `datestr`

Comment: DateField should just be a column name not a date, and thus should not have quotes around it. Otherwise your where condition is comparing two constants.